# Class with members created at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

We have a method, which returns the rows currently displayed in the grid.

```
public override List<object> GetData(int startIndex, int endIndex, string[] rowSortBy, bool[] rowAscSortOrder, 
                   string[] rowGroupByOperations, string rowFilterExpression, ref int rowCount)        
    {

          List<A> list =  new List<A>();
          .. logic..

          return list;        
    }
```

The problem is that now the grid columns are **dynamic**, they keep on changing depending on some conditions. This means we cannot use a typed class as the data members are dynamic. Plus we cannot change return type, `List<object>` of `GetData` method as this is actually used by a third party control.

**Edit**: And we need to do updates on the grid.

Only way I can think is to make class with use of reflection.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps something like a dictionary would be more appropriate?

Comment: The return type cannot be changed. List<object>. Dictionary does not implement IList.

Comment: But could you make each object in the list a dictionary with the column values?

Comment: GridControl cannot properly recognize data stored in the List of Dictionary objects. So if we return List<Dictionary>, it cannot be used as a grid data-source. I am now thinking to let go of this idea of a paged server side async grid and use a normal grid instead.

Comment: You *could* implement support for [ITypedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist.aspx) in a class of your own, but doing this, at least for hierarchical property references, is a major undertaking.

Comment: @Lasse: and then use List<Dictionary<string, string>>? will it allow data to be edited on the grid as well?

Comment: If you implement it correctly, yes, but it's a bit of work and lousy on documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to implement ICustomTypeDescriptor on the objects within your list.

This way a property is requested and you can return the relevant data with new properties at runtime.

http://wraithnath.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/implementing-icustomtypedescriptor-for.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163816.aspx

This took me a while to figure out the first time as it is a little complicated. It does however work!

Comment: @AseemGautam - yes, I have implemented in a project, the grid will work the same. It will attempt to set the property, and your Implementation will update the correct value within your object.